# Dropdown menu getting cut off

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, sass

I'm building a dropdown menu in rails. I have the menu in my application.html.erb file. Directly below it, I have my <%= yield %> tag where my content goes. My dropdown menu gets cut off when it goes outside of the header section and into the section area. I've checked overflow and none of them have it set to "hide". I'm not sure what's going on. The parent is being floated, if that matters. 
Can someone help?

Here is a pic of the issue:

[image]

Here is the CSS. I'm using SASS with media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 546px) {

$darker-grey: #3e3e3e; 
$dark-grey: #282828;
$gold: #ffd43e;
$light-grey: #b7b7b7; 



a {
    color: $light-grey;
    font-family: arial;
}

body {
    background-color: $dark-grey;
}


p {
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
}



h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
}


 label {
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    display:inline; 
    font-style: italic; 
  }

  header {
    width: calc(100% - 70px);
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: black;
    h1 {
        font-size: 28px; 
        color: $gold;
        float: left; 
    }
 }

.alert {
    color: red;
}
.book {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 230px; 
    height: 350px; 
}




.book_show {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline;
}


.btn {
    border: 2px solid $gold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80px;
    color: $gold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: arial;

}

.btn_left {
    border: 2px solid $gold;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    background-color: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80px;
    color: $gold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-family: arial;

}
.btn_right {
    border: 2px solid $gold;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    background-color: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80px;
    color: $gold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-family: arial;

}
.btn_center {
    border: 2px solid $gold;
    border-radius: 0px; 
    background-color: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80px;
    color: $gold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-family: arial;

}
.btn_submit {
        border-radius: 5px; 
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-top: 13px;
        padding-bottom: 13px; 
        background-color: $gold;
        color: white;
        border: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none; 
        font-family: arial; 
        font-size: 16px;
        display: inline-block; 
    }
.btn_submit:hover {
        background-color: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
}

.buttons {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: none;
            padding-top:30px;
            padding-bottom: 60px;
            clear: left;
            width: 323px;

}

.container_books_index {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 85%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: none; 
    display: inline-block; 
    display: block;

}



.container_books_show {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: none;  
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px; 
    display: inline-block; 

    h4 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px; 

    }
    h2 {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px; 
    }
    hr {
        margin-right: 30px; 
    }
    p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px; 
    }
    .inner_left {
        width: 323px; 
        background-color: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center; 
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;  
    }

}


.hide {
    display: none;  
}


.form_upload {
    color: white;
}


.remember {
            position: relative;
            top: -48px;
            left: 32px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

remember_label {
        text-align: left;
        width: 5px;  
}




.field_with_errors {
    color: red; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    font-family: arial;

}
.form {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    h2 {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;

    }
    input {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    textarea {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 120px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .submit {
        width: 150px;
        height: 40px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: $gold;
        color: white;
        border: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-left: 0px;

    }
    .submit:hover {
        background-color: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    span {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-style: italic;
    }
}

.menu_icon {
background-color: none;
padding: 0px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 30px; 
float: right;
margin-top: 0px; 
position: relative;
top: -10px; 
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: none;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
right: 0; 
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 }

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}


nav {
    background-color: none;
    padding-top: 13px;
    float: right;
    a {
        color: $gold;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: arial;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}

.notice {
    color: green;
}



section {
    overflow: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: none;
    display: inline-block; /* Necessary to trigger "hasLayout" in IE */
    display: block; /* Sets element back to block */
}

}
```

Here is my application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BookApp</title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>


<header>
<h1>Book Reviews</h1>
    <nav>



  <div class="dropdown">
      <img onclick="myFunction()" class="menu_icon" src="/assets/menu_icon.png">
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a class="hide_when_large" href="#home">Home</a>
          <a class="hide_when_large" href="#about">Logout</a>
          <a class="hide_when_large" href="#contact">Add Book</a>
        </div>
  </div>


   <!--<%= image_tag 'menu_icon', :class => "menu_icon" %>--> 






        <% if user_signed_in? then %>
            <%= link_to "Home", books_path, :class => "hide" %>

        <% end %>



        <% if user_signed_in? then %>
            <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => "hide"  %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => "hide"  %>
        <% end %>



        <% if user_signed_in? then %>
            <%= link_to "Add Book", new_book_path, :class => "hide"  %>
        <% end %>
    </nav>  
</header>


<%= yield %>
</body>


<script>

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.menu_icon')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}
</script>

</html>
```

Here is my show.html.erb. Please note it happens in EVERY view, not jsut this one, which leads me to believe the issue is with application.html.erb

```
<section>
<div class="container_books_show">

    <div class="inner_left">
    <%= image_tag @book.book_img.url, :class => "book_show" %>  
    <div class="buttons">

            <% if user_signed_in? then %>
                <% if current_user.id = @book.user_id %>
                    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_path, :class => "btn_left" %>
                    <%= link_to "Delete", book_path(@book), method: :delete, :class => "btn_right", data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
                 <% end %>  
             <% end %>
             <br />
             <%= link_to "Back", root_path, :class => "btn" %>
             <br />

             <%= link_to "Add Review", new_book_review_path(@book) , :class => "btn_submit" %>
        </div>  
    </div>


        <h2 class="title"><%= @book.title %></h2>
        <h4><%= @book.author %></h4>
        <div class="average-review-rating" data-score=<%= @average_review %>></div>
        <label>Average Rating</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p><%= @book.description %></p>
        <br />

        <% if @book.reviews.count >= 1 %>
            <h4>Reviews</h4>
        <% end %>

        <%= render @book.reviews %>


</div>
</section>
<script> 
$('.review-rating').raty({
readOnly: true,
score: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-number');
},
path: '/assets/'
});
 </script>

<script>
$('.average-review-rating').raty({
readOnly: true,
path: '/assets/',
score: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-score')
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a z-index problem.  Make sure that your drop down has a higher z-index than the other elements that you want to be underneath it.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I am completely stumped with this one.